# What is the most triangles you can make from a capital "H" and 3 straight lines?

Tags: mathematics, geometry, triangle

So start with an upper case H, and then draw $3$ straight lines. **What is the greatest number of closed triangles that you can form?** For example:

[image: an example]

Note that triangles inside of triangles only count once (e.g. 5 & 6 in the image don't count):
[image: however, triangles inside of other triangles do not count]

And you aren't allowed to extend the cross line of the H (e.g. 5 in the image doesn't count)
[image: Example of what's not allowed]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's a solution for 7 triangles:

> [image]

Comment: You can make $8$ from that picture. See if you can figure it out ;)

Comment: No, you cannot.

Comment: Decrease the angle between three red lines and rotate them ccw slightly. Now two rightmost red lines in the original form will make another triangle with the right pillar of H. According to OP only extending the cross line is not allowed.

Comment: @btw please draw a picture. The two rightmost red lines (the ones that go through the right edge of the picture) already make a triangle with the right pillar of the H, and hopefully you aren't suggesting that three straight lines could somehow make more than one triangle.

Comment: I was mistaken! After lots of analysis from drawing at home and all, methinks $7$ triangles is, in actual fact, the maximum amount that can be made from $3$ straight lines and with the OP's rules. My apologies! But, to your answer, my compliments! :D

Answer (score 6):

Here's one with *six* triangles (7 if you count triangles outside of triangles, which you don't):

> [image: H with lines]

Comment: I _suspect_ that this is the highest that can be gotten, but I'm not sure.

Comment: My friend alleges that he can get 7, but won't show me how. Considering writing a python script to help prove that 6 is the max. Also I feel like there may be a mathematical proof of this with analytical geometry

Comment: If you just moved all of your blue lines up or down a bit you’d get 7 won’t you.

Comment: @tyobrien you'd get one more triangle in the middle, but the two triangles right next to the new one would become quadrangles, right?

Comment: Oh yes that would be correct

Comment: Oh yeah @bass lol

Answer (score 3):

Does this count as 8 triangles?

> [image]

Comment: The question says "Note that triangles inside of triangles only count once", which (I think) is a more complicated way of saying "the triangles are not allowed to overlap".

Comment: @Bass Precisely!

Comment: @Bass it is possible to create two triangles that overlap, but neither is inside the other, so they're _not_ just different ways of saying the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this pic using 3 red lines on letter H.
I count 10 triangles

[image: total triangles 9]

Comment: Overlapping triangles are not counted, so there are only 5 in your arrangement.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with @JaapScherphuis

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Event with overlapping I count 6. How are there 10 here?

Comment: @PerpetualJ I count 10 with overlapping rot13(gbc bs gb u gb zvqqyr yvar gvzrf gjb naq gbc bs u gb obggbz erq yvar gvzrf gjb. ) not sure if that helps